# Access a file through server path

Tags: php

**Setup:**

The server path of the website is located at `/var/www/website/`. Here I have `index.php` file that's using jPlayer (audio player plugin) to play MP3s.

**Issue:**

I need to access the MP3 files from `/gdrive/MP3s/` (server path). E.g. `/gdrive/MP3s/sample.mp3`

On the code (`index.php`), I tried putting the MP3 path `/gdrive/MP3s/sample.mp3` on jPlayer but it didn't work (it's treating the path as `http://website.com/gdrive/MP3s/sample.mp3`).

Then I tried `../../../gdrive/MP3s/sample.mp3`. I thought it will do the trick but also, it didn't work.

**Question:**

How can I access the MP3 files based from above?

Last resort would be to create virtualhost for `/gdrive/MP3s/` but I want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(assuming you're using a linux machine)

Create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from your MP3 folder to a web-accessible location.

> ln -s /gdrive/MP3s/ /var/www/website/MP3s

Then you can access that folder at `http://yoursite.com/MP3s/bleh.mp3` and access the files through jplayer at `/MP3s/bleh.mp3`

Think of it like a shortcut link

Comment: I just tried this... It works! THANK YOU! Also, just learnt about `ln`. For newbie about `ln`, this'll [help](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ln.htm).

Comment: Glad I could be of some assistance!